# Is it possible for a given char entered with the current keyboard layout, to find what it would be in another layout?

Tags: winapi, layout, internationalization, keyboard

I'm on Windows (Win32). Imagine I typed a key 'K' in the US/UK Layout and ANSI Charset. I want to find out what the char it would be if the key is the same, but layout is Russian and Charset is the corresponding. So in other words I want implement automatic wrong layout detection/fixing using only Windows API (without prior knowledge of any language)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for the [Keyboard Convert Service](http://www.siao2.com/2005/08/20/454114.aspx).